# In what situations can methods of one class be invoked on objects of another?

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to Java so I'm still learning the rules of working in a strictly object-oriented language. Today I was wondering about using a method to work with objects outside of that method's class. Is it possible under any circumstance to successfully perform operations on an object with a method from another class?

Say I have an anchorPane object (javafx). It would not be sensible to try to invoke the setText() method of the Text class on it, because anchorPanes do not display text directly.

But, are there situations in which such a thing is possible? Is it always a rule that methods can only affect objects of their class?

Comment: _Only_ affect objects of their class -- no. Consider `public void m1(Integer[] nums)`. The method `m1` would be able to affect `nums` by modifying its elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it always a rule that methods can only affect objects of their class?

not directly, but if you mark a method as *protected*, the method can be invoked only from objects of same class and objects from derived classes (even on other instances). See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

In addition, you can make it final, so that it is not possible to overrule the method (and if you make your class final, nobody can derive from your class). in this case, you get exactly what you described:

```
//final here disallows to subclass "Sample". This assures that there exists NO subclass that invokes bar().
public final class Sample {


    public void foo() {

        //on same instance
        this.bar();

        //on another instance, but just same class (or subclass of Sample, but not possible because class is final)
        Sample b = new Sample();
        b.bar();
    }

    /*final here prevents that METHOD is overwritten. But class can be overwritten.
     * subclasses are also allowed to invoke bar().
     */
    protected final void bar() {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In what situations can methods of one class be invoked on objects of another?

Every class (and interface) defines methods that can be invoked on it.

Java being a typesafe language, it does not allow you to invoke a method written for a specific class on something that is not an instance of that class (something you *could* do in Javascript for example, by using `bind(iWantThisThis)`).

It is not possible to invoke these methods on instances of completely unrelated classes. They would need to be of that class or of a subclass.

So, no, you cannot invoke `Text::getText` on an instance of the unrelated `AnchorPane`.

You can invoke common methods from a shared parent interface or superclass. For example both `anchorPane.toString()` and `text.toString()` will work (because every Object in Java has these methods). If `AnchorPane` and `Text` both happen to be implementing a hypothetical `UIComponent` interface, there might be a `getSize()` method on both of them.

---

What I think you are looking for is called delegation or object composition. If you have an `AnchorPane` that displays a `Text`, you can give it a method that is also called `setText` that *delegates* the method call to a `Text` instance contained in the `AnchorPane`.

```
class AnchorPane {
    private final Text myText;
    void setText(String newText){
      myText.setText(myText);
    }
}
```

So now you also have a `setText` method on `AnchorPane` (but you had to add it manually to specify what exactly it does, and it does not give you any of the other methods).

Comment: but without a modifier, as in your sample), it is package-private. if you have it package-private, or public, there is no protection to invoke the method from any other object of any other class (which has to be in same package, with package-private i.e. no modifier).

Only with "protected", you can restrict access so that just subclasses and other instances of same object can access it

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. I assume it is asking "Can I invoke methods of Text *from* another class like AnchorPane". Or maybe "Can I invoke methods from Text *on* another class like AnchorPane".

Comment: Probably you are right... I focused on "It would not be sensible to try to invoke the setText() method of the Text class on it, because anchorPanes do not display text directly." - this told me he wants to disallow invocation of setText from other classes' instances..

Comment: And the answer as stated is incorrect. You have to have an instance of the *class*, which is an object, or a subclass.